# How to install Mozilla Firefox on kubuntu 12.04?

Tags: firefox, kubuntu

I have installed Kubuntu 12.04 on my netbook. Each time I invoke the Firefox Installer, it downloads a package, and nothing happens.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Show us the commands that you are using.

Comment: had the same issue Kubuntu 12.04 seems to ship with a lot of software sources disabled by default. enable through muon and let it update sources then install as per usual good luck

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install software graphically in Kubuntu you need to use an application called Muon. You can also install packages from the command line by opening a terminal and typing, for the example related to your question, `sudo apt-get install firefox`. `sudo` tells the computer you want to do the following action with administrative privileges, `apt-get` is an application to install software and `firefox` is the name of the package you want to install. The terminal will ask for your password and, once you give it, apt-get will do the rest.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did it using the apt-get command and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

When you said "invoking the Firefox installer", do you mean downloading it on their website?

If it is the case, Firefox is into the package you downloaded. Unpack the package (with the [archive manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/file-roller/), for example) and you will find a folder called "firefox" containing the program.

Comment: The package "Firefox installer" was already available after I installed kubuntu from the scratch. I was wondering, why only an "installer" was provided. Anyway, the installation with the apt-get command worked well. Thanks for help!